# For loops seems to run double than what is expected

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm having issues with leetcode algo question 1252. I'm not sure why but my for loop seems to run twice. The question is:

"Given n and m which are the dimensions of a matrix initialized by zeros and given an array indices where indices[i] = [ri, ci]. For each pair of [ri, ci] you have to increment all cells in row ri and column ci by 1.

Return the number of cells with odd values in the matrix after applying the increment to all indices."

```js
var oddCells = function(n, m, indices) {

  let matrix = [];
  let array = Array(m).fill(0);
  let k = 0;
  while (k < n) {
    matrix.push(array);
    k++;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    const row = indices[i][0];
    const col = indices[i][1];

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      matrix[j][col]++;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
      matrix[row][i]++;
    }

  }

  return matrix.flat().filter(number => number % 2 !== 0).length;
}

console.log(oddCells(2, 3, [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 1]
]));
```

The specific input I am testing is `n = 2, m = 3, indices = [[0,1],[1,1]]`.

I've tried to follow my code manually but I can't figure out why the two inner for loops are iterating over the nested arrays twice rather than each one once. After the first loop[ the matrix is supposed to be `[[1, 2, 1], [0, 1, 0]]` but instead I end up with `[[1, 3, 1], [1, 3, 1]]`.

Comment: Haven't read the entire code, but I see you reused the `i` variable in an inner loop that already uses it. Edit: Maybe that doesn't matter because of `let`, but I still wouldn't do it.

Comment: @slappy i tried a different variable just in case but yeah it didn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic problem of reusing mutable reference values.

You are repeatedly pushing the same array to the matrix, so when you modify any value in that array, you are modifying multiple areas of the matrix.

So use separate arrays:

```js
var oddCells = function(n, m, indices) {

  let matrix = [];
  let k = 0;
  while (k < n) {
    matrix.push(Array(m).fill(0));
    k++;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    const row = indices[i][0];
    const col = indices[i][1];

    for (let ri = 0; ri < n; ri++) {
      matrix[ri][col]++;
    }

    for (let ci = 0; ci < m; ci++) {
      matrix[row][ci]++;
    }

  }

  return matrix.flat().filter(number => number % 2 !== 0).length;
}

console.log(oddCells(2, 3, [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 1]
]));
```